# Batch IF ELSE statement both execute

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

The batch file execute both the commands in IF and ELSE. I checked the syntax and space, no idea what is wrong.

```
IF EXIST C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome (
    start chrome www.google.com
) ELSE (
    start iexplore www.google.com
)
```

Both chrome and IE are opened as if the statement is not working.

Comment: The path has spaces _and_ `()` so it must be quoted `IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome"`.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space in the path passed to the exist test is confusing the parser. In general you should place quotes around such names.

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome" ( 
start chrome www.google.com
) ELSE ( 
start iexplore www.google.com 
)
```

Comment: Quotes. Quotes everywhere. That's how i write!

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the belated update, but I faced a similar issue and it turned out to be due to a parenthesis in a command line status message using echo. This caused both branches of the if/else statement to execute.

echo The GUID is %retrievedGUID%, now get original key value (folder path)